# Add Content to wordpress page template

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add content to a custom wordpress page template so that every new post is populated with the same information.

I have created a page design using shortcodes (visual composer plugin) which has generated a page design, which I would basically like to pre populate using a custom template for example: single-release.php...

The page template:

```
   <?php
/*
** page.php
** mk_build_main_wrapper : builds the main divisions that contains the content. Located in framework/helpers/global.php
** mk_get_view gets the parts of the pages, modules and components. Function located in framework/helpers/global.php
*/

get_header();


Mk_Static_Files::addAssets('mk_button'); 
Mk_Static_Files::addAssets('mk_audio');
Mk_Static_Files::addAssets('mk_swipe_slideshow');

mk_build_main_wrapper( mk_get_view('singular', 'wp-page', true) );

get_footer();
```

The content I wish to pre populate:

```
[mk_page_section bg_color="#202020" attachment="fixed" bg_position="center top" bg_repeat="no-repeat" bg_stretch="true" js_vertical_centered="true" padding_top="70" padding_bottom="30" sidebar="sidebar-1"][vc_column width="1/3"][vc_single_image source="featured_image" img_size="large"][/vc_column][vc_column width="2/3"][vc_row_inner][vc_column_inner width="1/2"][vc_column_text el_class="t"]ARTIST[/vc_column_text][mk_custom_sidebar el_class="title" sidebar="sidebar-19"][vc_column_text el_class="trackname"]RELEASE: [acf field="track_name"][/vc_column_text][vc_column_text margin_bottom="30" el_class="date"]RELEASE DATE: [acf field="release_date"][/vc_column_text][vc_column_text el_class="date"]TRACKS[/vc_column_text][vc_column_text el_class="track"]01. [acf field="track_01"][/vc_column_text][vc_column_text el_class="track"]02. [acf field="track_02"][/vc_column_text][vc_column_text el_class="track"]04. [acf field="track_03"][/vc_column_text][vc_column_text el_class="track"]03. [acf field="track_04"][/vc_column_text][vc_column_text el_class="track"]05. [acf field="track_05"][/vc_column_text][mk_padding_divider size="20"][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner el_class="columnbuttons" width="1/2"][vc_column_text el_class="trackname"]PURCHASE:[/vc_column_text][mk_custom_sidebar el_class="buybutton" sidebar="sidebar-18"][vc_column_text el_class="trackname"]LISTEN[/vc_column_text][vc_column_text el_class="track"][acf field="audio_embed"][/vc_column_text][/vc_column_inner][/vc_row_inner][/vc_column][/mk_page_section][mk_page_section bg_color="#303030" padding_top="40" padding_bottom="40" sidebar="sidebar-1"][vc_column][mk_fancy_title color="#f2f2f2" size="20" font_weight="300" txt_transform="uppercase" margin_bottom="0" font_family="none"]NEW RELEASES[/mk_fancy_title][ess_grid alias="Single-page-releases"][/vc_column][/mk_page_section]
```

is this possible? / how would I go about doing this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter the Page template of your Theme, you have to edit the files located in themes/yourtheme/views/singular/wp-page.php.

The file you are trying to edit is just kinda accessing a function in the global.php file which will then load the specific files for the page.

Btw. you can execute the shortcodes in php with

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[SHORTCODE_EXAMPLE]"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if mk_page_section is a shortcode you are creating yourself you need to write a function to do this.

you can create your own, and with Visual composer you can add your own shortcodes too. Google how to integrate your shortcode into VC, which uses a php class extension.

Either way you have to register your shortcode with WordPress using the add_shortcode function.

An example shortcode is.

in your functions.php you can add a shortcode.

```
add_shortcode('my-magic-shortcode','myCustomFunction');
function myCustomFunction($atts){
    global $post;
    /// note these defaults can be overridden
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'bg_color' => '#fff',
            'attachment' =>  'fixed',
            'bg_position' => 'center top',
            'bg_stretch' => 'contain',
            ///// add more defaults
        ), $atts, 'my-magic-shortcode');

   echo '<div style="background-color:'.$atts['bg_color'].';background-attachment:'.$atts['attachment'].';background-position:'.$atts['bg_position'].';background-stretch:'.$atts['bg_stretch'].';" >'.wpautop($post->post_content).'</div>';
   //// alternatively you could use a return to send all this back to a variable for use later in your page
   //// just comment out the line that echos the string above
   $str_html = '<div style="background-color:'.$atts['bg_color'].';background-attachment:'.$atts['attachment'].';background-position:'.$atts['bg_position'].';background-stretch:'.$atts['bg_stretch'].';" >'.wpautop($post->post_content).'</div>';
   return $str_html;
}
```